# Pointwise limit of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f_n:[-2,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
-n^2 |x|+n, |x| \leq \frac{1}{n}\\
0, |x| > \frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}.$$
I need to find the pointwise limit of this sequence of function.

 Of course, if $x \in (\infty,-\frac{1}{n}) \cup (\frac{1}{n},\infty)$, then $f_n(x)=0$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=0$.

 If we fix $x \in [-\frac{1}{n},0)$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2x+n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2(x+\frac{1}{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2x=\infty.$$

 If we fix $x \in (0,\frac{1}{n}]$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-n^2x+n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2(-x+\frac{1}{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}-n^2x=-\infty.$$
I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: You are using $n$ in 2 different ways as if they were the same  thing. E.g . if $x\in (0,1/n]$... for which $n$?  Certainly not for infinitely many $n.$

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not correct. For pointwise convergence you cannot make $x$ dependent on $n$. Fix any $x \neq 0$. Then $|x| >\frac 1 n$ for $n$ sufficiently large so $f_n(x)=0$ for such $n$. Hence the limit is $0$ for all $x \neq 0$. Clearly the limit is $\infty$ for $x=0$.